# Plotting histograms with bin count multiplied by some factor

Tags: plotting, histograms

Consider, for example

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.6], 1000]]
```

which gives me,

[image]

Now, is there a way to change the bin counts, as in, I want to multiply some factor to the bin counts (lets say "0.5"). meaning there should be only about 70 events(y-axis) at -0.5 (x-axis) instead of about 140 events. how do I reflect this on this histogram?

--Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The function `fh` in `Histogram[data, bspec, fh]` is applied to two arguments: a list of bins `{{b1, b2}, {b2, b3}, ...}`, and a corresponding list of counts `{c1, c2, ...}`. The function should return a list of heights to be used for each of the `ci`].

So you just need to use a height function to scale the list of counts:

```
Histogram[data, Automatic, .5 #2 &]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! just what I was looking for! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use the option `ChartElementFunction` with a function that modifies the built-in functions to change the appropriate element of rectangle coordinates:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.6], 1000]; 
Histogram[data, {-2, 2, .2}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementData["Rectangle"][{{1, 1}, {1, .5}} #, ##2] &)]
```

[image]

The advantages of this approach are  (1) you can use other built-in height functions such as `"PDF"` without additional work, (2) you can have multiple datasets each with its own scaling (as long as you don't need them `"Stacked"`), and (3) you can use the tooltips to see the unscaled values of bar heights.

The simple method above works only for the default setting (`"Bottom"`) for the option `BarOrigin`. The following function makes this approach work for non-default `BarOrigin` settings:

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF[sc_ : 1][cedf_ : "Rectangle", o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Module[{origin = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BarOrigin"], box = #}, 
     Switch[origin, 
       Bottom, box[[2, 2]] = sc box[[2, 2]],
       Top, box[[2, 1]] = sc box[[2, 1]], 
       Left, box[[1, 2]] = sc box[[1, 2]],
       Right, box[[1, 1]] = sc box[[1, 1]]];
     ChartElementDataFunction[cedf, o][box, ##2]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
 Histogram[data, {-2, 2, .2}, "PDF", ImageSize -> 300, 
  BarOrigin -> Bottom, ChartElementFunction -> ceF[.5][] ]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[data, {-2, 2, .2}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   ImageSize -> 200, BarOrigin -> #, 
   ChartElementFunction -> ceF[.5][]] & /@ {Bottom, Top, Left,  Right} // 
 Grid[Partition[#, 2], Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

Multiple datasets each with its own scaling:

```
Histogram[{data, data}, {-2, 2, .2}, ChartElementFunction -> {ceF[.5][], ceF[.8][]}]
```

[image]